# max value of /camera/depth/image_raw is 8 bit 256 not 16bit?

Tags: ros, kinect, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm running ros diamondback.

Documentation states that is should be uint16 to represent mm. So i'm expecting values two bytes long, but instead all I get is values one byte long, max of 256!
I require the depth values so I can know how far an object is, that is all I need, I dont need to work with any other library. I have searched and searched for days and cannot find a proper solution!

So again, all i need is a registered depth value image, I want to be able to get the value and calculate the distance in that pixel.

```
depth/image_raw (sensor_msgs/Image)
Raw image from device. Contains uint16 depths in mm.
```

what to do?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32908/max-value-of-/camera/depth/image_raw-is-8-bit-256-not-16bit!?/) by [Maltenrazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2265/maltenrazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-04-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-29**:
Please list the output from "rostopic echo /depth/image_raw/encoding"

**Comment by [Maltenrazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2265/maltenrazer/) on 2012-04-29**:
http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v67/maltenrazer/kinect_depth.png .. I used cout << image.get()->encoding << "\n"; to get the encoding output

**Comment by [Maltenrazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2265/maltenrazer/) on 2012-04-29**:
I have a bizarre problem where the left top and right edges are completely black any ideas? I have tried turning on and off depth registration by using rosparam get /openni_node1/depth_registration to see if it has an effect, but no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [`sensor_msgs/Image`](http://ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html), the `data` field is uint8 [0..255], but is interpreted according to the `encoding` and `is_bigendian` fields. Unfortunately, the 16-bit encodings did not work correctly in some Diamondback tools. They work better in Electric and Fuerte.

What `encoding` do your messages report?

UPDATE: 32FC1 is an opencv 32-bit float encoding. Perhaps [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/10222/openni_camera-depth-image-opencv) is helpful.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1